# Does LSTM need all steptime shift for parameter identification of a model?

Tags: python, keras, lstm

I use LSTM deep learning to identify parameters of a mathematical model which generate a univariate time series. According to the parameters I choose for the model, the time series will change in it's oscillation frequency or shape (type of oscillation).

For now, I made a Deep learning LSTM that's taking 1 second of the time series (1024 samples)

```
DLmodel = Sequential()
DLmodel.add(LSTM(units=Nb_input, return_sequences=True, input_shape=(None, Nb_input), activation='sigmoid'))  
DLmodel.add(Dropout(0.3))
DLmodel.add(Dense(Nb_input // 4, activation="relu", kernel_initializer="uniform"))
DLmodel.add(Dropout(0.3))
DLmodel.add(Dense(Nb_input // 8, activation="relu", kernel_initializer="uniform"))
DLmodel.add(Dropout(0.3)) 
DLmodel.add(Dense(Nb_output, activation="linear", kernel_initializer="uniform"))
```

where

```
Nb_input = number of sample
Nb_output = number of parameter to identify
```

My idea is to do

```
while 1:
    label = randomly choose 3 model parameters N times (dimension = 1 x N x 3) 
    signal = generate N signal of 5 seconds (dimension = 1 x N x 1024) 
    
    increase the training set by using a shift window on the time series 
    training set = windowed signal (dimension = 1 x N*5 x 1024)
    label = copy model parameters(dimension = 1 x N*5 x 3) 
    
    Fit the LSTM
    
    Test LSTM on new data
```

What I'm wondering is, does LSTM inputs need to have a time shift of 1 sample (to create the training set) to be correctly trained or can I leave the time shift to a complete window (1024 samples)? For instance, if I have an event at the beginning of the one second window, does it is the same (for the LSTM point of view) as if the event is at the end?

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to split the data for training, for example:
Assume you have a dataset

```
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
```

We split sequences into a list of subsequences of length: `m`, and we denote the delay between each sequence as: `d`. This is called **Takens embedding**.

Therefore for example if `d=m=4`

```
[1,2,3,4][5,6,7,8]
```

or if we set `d=1` and `m=4` we obtain:

```
[1,2,3,4][2,3,4,5][3,4,5,6][4,5,6,7][5,6,7,8]
```

Any `d>1` and `m>1` is valid.
The choice of how you pre-process the dataset depends on your problem.
What I suggest is to try various windowing techniques and then compare results. There is no golden rule in terms of choice of window size, to my knowledge.